# Sending multiple emails from multiple queries using one command button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am fairly new to VBA coding and from being helped on here. I have managed to create some code to send an email using a query. However, if possible I would like to send multiple emails, using different queries by clicking one command button.

```vba
Private Sub Command161_Click()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olItem As Variant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQry As String
    Dim aHead(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aRow(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aBody() As String
    Dim lCnt As Long

    'Create the header row
    aHead(1) = "ID"
    aHead(2) = "Title"
    aHead(3) = "Priority"
    aHead(4) = "Requested By"
    aHead(5) = "Type of task"
    aHead(6) = "Start Date"
    aHead(7) = "Due Date"

    lCnt = 1
    ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
    aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

    'Create each body row
    strQry = "SELECT * From [OutstandingTasks-John]"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
        Do While Not rec.EOF
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
            aRow(1) = rec("ID")
            aRow(2) = rec("Title")
            aRow(3) = rec("Priority")
            aRow(4) = rec("Requested By")
            aRow(5) = rec("Type of task")
            aRow(6) = rec("Start Date")
            aRow(7) = rec("Due Date")

            aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

    'create the email
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    olItem.Display
    olItem.To = "john.smith@johnsmith.com"
    olItem.Subject = "Outstanding Tasks"
    olItem.HTMLBody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
    olItem.Display
End Sub
```

From the code above, an email will be sent to John Smith with the list of his outstanding tasks using the query [OutstandingTasks-John].

However, from the same action button I would like to send Emily Smith an email separately with her list of outstanding tasks using the query [OutstandingTasks-Emily].

I can just copy the and paste underneath the original code and change it slightly but how do i join these two sets of code?

Also as a nice to have. When i send the email to John Smith. It comes up in outlook and I have to manually send it. How can I automatically send this from the action button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just copy paste the code. You just need to update the portions that should contain Emily instead of John.

Now, moving forward, if John and Emily become John, Emily, Carla and Steve you should think about merging Johns task table and Emily's task table so there is a shared table for all tasks and then putting the *name and email* you're sending the email to in the select query, then we can just loop *that* recordset instead of copy pasting the same code blocks.

To send and email using the method below, you just need to add `olItem.Send`

Also, its good to make sure that you're dimming things for a reason AND cleaning up after yourself with `set [object] = Nothing` when you're done with it.

**Immediate Fix**

```
Private Sub Command161_Click()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olItem As Variant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQry As String
    Dim aHead(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aRow(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aBody() As String
    Dim lCnt As Long

    'Create the header row
    aHead(1) = "ID"
    aHead(2) = "Title"
    aHead(3) = "Priority"
    aHead(4) = "Requested By"
    aHead(5) = "Type of task"
    aHead(6) = "Start Date"
    aHead(7) = "Due Date"

    lCnt = 1
    ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
    aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

    'Create each body row
    strQry = "SELECT * From [OutstandingTasks-John]"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
        Do While Not rec.EOF
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
            aRow(1) = rec("ID")
            aRow(2) = rec("Title")
            aRow(3) = rec("Priority")
            aRow(4) = rec("Requested By")
            aRow(5) = rec("Type of task")
            aRow(6) = rec("Start Date")
            aRow(7) = rec("Due Date")

            aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

    'create the email
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    olItem.Display
    olItem.To = "john.smith@johnsmith.com"
    olItem.Subject = "Outstanding Tasks"
    olItem.HTMLBody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
    olItem.Display
    olItem.Send



    'EMILY code block

    ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
    aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

    'Create each body row
    strQry = "SELECT * From [OutstandingTasks-Emily]"
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
        Do While Not rec.EOF
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
            aRow(1) = rec("ID")
            aRow(2) = rec("Title")
            aRow(3) = rec("Priority")
            aRow(4) = rec("Requested By")
            aRow(5) = rec("Type of task")
            aRow(6) = rec("Start Date")
            aRow(7) = rec("Due Date")

            aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"


    'create the email
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    olItem.Display
    olItem.To = "emily.smith@emilysmith.com"
    olItem.Subject = "Outstanding Tasks"
    olItem.HTMLBody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
    olItem.Display
    olItem.Send

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set rec = Nothing
    set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Future Consideration**

```
Private Sub Command161_Click()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olItem As Variant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQry As String
    Dim aHead(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aRow(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aBody() As String
    Dim lCnt As Long


    Dim personRS as DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set personRS = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, PERSON_EMAIL FROM [CombinedTaskList])

    If Not (personRS.BOF and personRS.EOF) Then

        'Create the header row
        aHead(1) = "ID"
        aHead(2) = "Title"
        aHead(3) = "Priority"
        aHead(4) = "Requested By"
        aHead(5) = "Type of task"
        aHead(6) = "Start Date"
        aHead(7) = "Due Date"


        Do While Not personRS.EOF
            lCnt = 1
            ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
            aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

            'Create each body row
            strQry = "SELECT * From [CombinedTaskList] WHERE PERSON = " & personRS("PERSON")
            Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(strQry)

            If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
                Do While Not rec.EOF
                    lCnt = lCnt + 1
                    ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
                    aRow(1) = rec("ID")
                    aRow(2) = rec("Title")
                    aRow(3) = rec("Priority")
                    aRow(4) = rec("Requested By")
                    aRow(5) = rec("Type of task")
                    aRow(6) = rec("Start Date")
                    aRow(7) = rec("Due Date")

                    aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
                    rec.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If

            aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

            'create the email
            Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
            Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

            olItem.Display
            olItem.To = personRS("PERSON_EMAIL")
            olItem.Subject = "Outstanding Tasks"
            olItem.HTMLBody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
            olItem.Send

            Set olApp = Nothing
            Set olItem = Nothing

            personRS.MoveNext

        Loop

    End If

    Set personRS = Nothing
    Set rec = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you very much for your help. I will take your comments into consideration and look at merging the tables.